# Simulate one color printing using Fabric.js

Tags: image-processing, printing, fabricjs

I would like to apply filters to a full color image using Fabric.js in order to simulate what it would look like if the image were to be printed using only one color of ink. Much like grayscale, but with an arbitrary base color instead of gray. My approach so far has been to convert the image to grayscale and then adjust the brightness and apply a tint or overlay using BlendColor. This solution tends to give images that are too dark or washed out. What's the most technically correct/accurate way to do this?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
var grayscale = ThirdPartyLibrary.getFilter('grayscale'); // using the grayscale filter from another lib
var brightness = new fabric.Image.filters.Brightness({
  brightness: 0.2
});
var tint = new fabric.Image.filters.BlendColor({
  color: '#3b7998',
  mode: 'tint',
  alpha: 0.5
});

element.applyFilters([grayscale, brightness, tint]);
```

Any input is appreciated, even if just the basic approach and I can figure out how to implement the filters in Fabric.js.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get an effect like this:

[image]

You should be able to obtain it with using first the greyscale filter of fabricJS with the `average` mode, and then the blendColor with `multiply` mode.

Image luminance shouldn't change, but it won't work perfectly with all colors.

You need to pick up colors that have max saturation and lightness at 50%.
You have just the HUE as a free parameter.

You can generate them with the fabric color utils:

```js
    const hsl = `hsl(${Math.round(value * 360)}, 100%, 50%)`;
    const [r,g,b] = fabric.Color.sourceFromHsl(hsl);
```